# ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'example.com' doesn't match either of 'exampleserver.com'?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

when I'm trying open a website with urllib library I'm getting the error. I'm not getting why this error occurs? currently I'm using python 3.6 version. Is this problem with version?

```
url = 'https://example.com'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
text = get_text(html)
data = text.split()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by this code:

## need to import ssl library

import ssl

## need to add this code before loading url

ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True

Example:

```
import ssl

ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True
url = 'https://example.com'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
text = get_text(html)
data = text.split()
print(data)
```

Comment: So basically you are returning true in every case. This can be risky from security point of view. You should atleast check for valid cert and its expiration.

Comment: how to check for valid certificate ?

Comment: seems like in python, we have separate handlers for checking the cert expiry and host name. So, whatever you are doing is correct. You need not validate cert here. There is separate callback "cert_time_to_seconds(cert_time)" that gets called for validating cert.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the common name of your SSL/TLS Certificate does not match the domain name of you site. Try changing the domain name of your site to exampleServer.Com and see if it works.    Otherwise, you will have to write custom logic to ignore name mismatch error.

Comment: custom logic in the sense including "try block" to avoid error?

Comment: I am not sure about python. But generally in every framework, there are callback methods which get called when SSL handshake takes place. By default, this method returns true only when all the validation passes. However, you can write your own logic to ignore name mismatch error and return true from this method. You can search for this callback method in Python